# Using regex to select hide matching words - MS Word

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a macro for ms word, for finding all matching words using regex and setting them as hidden. I am able to run the macro without errors, but without any result. When I use some word instead of regex, the macro works. Is the regex wrong for VBA or macro is incorrect? I am lost, could you please help?

Macro:

```
Sub HideElements()
  Dim oRng As Word.Range
  Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range

  With oRng.Find
    .Text = "(?'Name'.*?),.*?\| Pnumber:(?'Pnumber'.*?)\| INumber:(?'Inumber'\d+)\|?.*?$\n(?'Addr'.*?.?)\|.*?$"
    .Replacement.Font.Hidden = True
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
```

Sample text:

> John Serato, Active | Pnumber: A99999-CC | INumber:9139229719 | AAV
>   Certified 
>       New York, NY, USA | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididun

Comment: You are not using a regex here, you are using `.MatchWildcards = True`.

Answer (score 0):

Word's *wildcards* are not directly equivalent to RegEx. Try something along the lines of:

```
Sub HideElements()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .Text = "[!^13]@| Pnumber:[!^13]@| INumber:[!^13]@|[!^13]@|*^13"
  .Format = True
  .Forward = True
  .Replacement.Font.Hidden = True
  .Replacement.Text = "^&"
  .MatchWildcards = True
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```